# Как сделать, чтобы значение из базы было выбрано в теге option используя freemarker

Tags: spring, freemarker

Есть форма, которая редактирует данные. Мне нужно, чтобы в поле option при заходе на страницу отображалось текущее значение из базы, которое в последствии можно было бы изменить на другое из выпадающего списка.

```
<form action="/editcruise" method="post">
    <label>Дата <input type="date" name="date" value="${date}"></label>
    <label>Время<input type="time" value=${cruise.time} name="time" /></label>
<label>Экскурсия
<select name="excursion">
    <#list excursions?if_exists as excursion>
        <option value="${excursion.name}">${excursion.name}</option>
    </#list>
</select></label>

<label>Корабль
<select name="ship">
    <#list ships?if_exists as ship>
        <option value="${ship.id}">${ship.name}</option>
    </#list>
</select></label>

<input type="hidden" value="${cruise.id}" name="cruiseId">
<input type="hidden" value="${_csrf.token}" name="_csrf">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Контроллер

```
@GetMapping("/cruise/{cruise}")
public String editCruise(@PathVariable Cruise cruise, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("date", format.format(cruise.getDate()));
    model.addAttribute("cruise",cruise);
    model.addAttribute("excursions",excursionRepo.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("ships",shipRepo.findAll());
    return "cruiseEdit";
}
```

Класс Cruise содержит поле Excursion

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@NotNull
private Date date;

@NotNull
private String time;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "excursion_id")
@NotNull
private Excursion excursion;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ship_id")
@NotNull
private Ship ship;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/editcruise" method="post">
    <label>Дата <input type="date" name="date" value="${date}"></label>
    <label>Время<input type="time" value=${cruise.time} name="time" /></label>
<label>Экскурсия
<select name="excursion">
    <#list excursions?if_exists as excursion >
        <#if excursion.id = cruise.excursion.id>
            <option value="${excursion.name}" selected>${excursion.name}</option>
        <#else>
            <option value="${excursion.name}">${excursion.name}</option>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</select></label>

<label>Корабль
<select name="ship">
    <#list ships?if_exists as ship>
        <#if ship.id = cruise.ship.id>
            <option value="${ship.name}" selected>${ship.name}</option>
        <#else>
            <option value="${ship.name}">${ship.name}</option>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</select></label>

<input type="hidden" value="${cruise.id}" name="cruiseId">
<input type="hidden" value="${_csrf.token}" name="_csrf">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Конструкция if - else